# Asymptotic variance of estimated AR(1) coefficient

Tags: time-series, estimation, least-squares, asymptotics

Consider an $AR(1)$ process

\begin{align*}
y_{t} + a y_{t-1} &= e_{t}
\end{align*}

for $t=1,\ldots,N$, where $e_{t}$ is a white Gaussian noise with variance $\sigma^{2}$.

How do I express the asymptotic variance of the OLS estimate of $a$ using $N$, $a$ and $\sigma^{2}$? Moreover, what is the asymptotic distribution of the OLS estimate of $a$? Assume $|a| < 1$.

Answer (score 3):

For $Y_t=\phi Y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$, with $\epsilon_t\sim (0,\sigma^2)$, we have
$$
\hat{\phi}=\frac{\sum_ty_{t-1}y_{t}}{\sum_ty_{t-1}^2}
$$
Hence, 
\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{T}(\hat{\phi}-\phi)&\to_d& N(0,\sigma^2E(Y_{t-1}^2)^{-1})\notag\\
&=&N(0,\sigma^2\gamma_0^{-1})\notag\\
&=&N(0,\sigma^2[\sigma^2/(1-\phi^2)]^{-1})\notag\\
&=&N(0,1-\phi^2)
\end{eqnarray}
A proof of intermediate steps may for example be found in Hamilton, Time Series Analysis, Chapter 7.